# google chrome: make find on page work for entire page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

It looks like "Find on page" actually only finds on the current screen, or content closest to one displayed at the moment. This mostly occurs on pages/websites with a long feed of content. Like Reddit or Twitter.

It's not a problem with dynamic content loading, even if you search after all content has been loaded, it still will not find anything that is far from the current screen.

Is this an option to disable this feature? Maybe some extension that can make the search on page actually *search on page*.?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it with the
[World's Longest Website](http://www.worldslongestwebsite.com/)
and, in effect, Chrome has a bug with very long pages.

Chrome for me seems to find the searched text, but be unable to position
to it.

It does indicate that it found the text, but stops positioning forward
somewhere in the middle of the page.

The only thing you can do is to signal the bug.
If you wish an immediate solution, you need to use another browser,
for example Firefox.